# Multiple select in an for loop is losing it's data when returning to the form

Tags: php, arrays, multiple-select

I have an form with an multiple select in the while loop:

```
while ($row_i = mysql_fetch_array($res_i))
{
    $i++;

    // maak select name
    $name_bewerking_id = 'bewerking_id'.$i;
    ?>

    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
        <select name="<?php echo $name_bewerking_id ?>[]" multiple="multiple" size="2">
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT id, bewerking FROM bewerkingen ORDER BY bewerking ASC";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
            { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['bewerking']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

When the form is send:

```
$bewerking_id[$i] = array();
$bewerking_id[$i] = $_POST['name_bewerking_id'][$i];

if(isset($bewerking_id_temp[$i]))
{
    foreach($bewerking_id_temp[$i] as $temp[$i])
    {
        array_push($bewerking_id[$i], $temp[$i]);
    }
}
```

Returning to the form:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $aantal_regels_corr; $i++)
{
    // maak select name
    $name_bewerking_id = 'bewerking_id'.$i;
    ?>

    <tr valign="top">
        <td>
        <select name="<?php echo $name_bewerking_id ?>[]" multiple="multiple" size="2">
        <?php
            $sql = "SELECT id, bewerking FROM bewerkingen ORDER BY bewerking ASC";
            $res = mysql_query($sql,$con);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
            { ?>
                <option <?php if(isset($bewerking_id[$i]) && in_array($row['id'], $bewerking_id[$i])){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['bewerking']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

When returning to the form (when one of the other fields is not filled in) the chosen option(s) are lost and not selected again.

Where did I messed up?

Answer (score 0):

You read POST data with this identifier `'name_bewerking_id'`

but the select name is given by `<?php echo $name_bewerking_id ?>` with `$name_bewerking_id = 'bewerking_id'.$i`

Comment: and you also add "[]" at the end of the select name... why?

Comment: I added [] because it's an array, same result without the []. I have changed the identifier. Did not work

Answer (score 0):

If assuming you are passing the form information between 3 different pages, you will need to use $_SESSION variables for that. Normal PHP variables cannot be passed between pages, only $_SESSION variables.

For example:

**Page 1**

```
<form ...>
    <input name="text1" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Page 2**

```
// must start the session before session variables can be used
start_session();

$inputTextBox1 = $_SESSION["textBox1"] = $_POST["text1"];
```

**Page 3**

```
<?php start_session(); ?>
<html>
    ...

    <form ...>
        <select>
            <?php while ... { ?>
                <option <?php if(!empty($_SESSION["textBox1"])) { echo "selected=\"selected\""; } ?>>Some Text</option>
            <?php } // End while ?>
        </select>
    </form>

    ...
</html>
```